# What is the use of an LCL Filter?

Tags: filter, power-electronics

Can someone explain what is the use of an LCL filter and where is it used? I searched for it online but couldn't find any materials.

Comment: other names are \$Pi\$ and T filters.

Comment: I understand its called by Pi & T Filter but I see only a CLC type filter online not much of LCL filters that was one of the reason why I posted it here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- An LCL filter in a π configuration is a high-pass filter.
- An LCL filter in a T configuration is a low-pass filter.
- A CLC filter in a π configuration is a low-pass filter.
- A CLC filter in a T configuration is a high-pass filter.

Depending on the cutoff frequency and input/output impedances desired for either a low-pass or a high-pass filter, one or the other of the possible configurations will lend itself to a better implementation.

In general, you'll tend to see more CLC filters than LCL filters because capacitors tend to be smaller and cheaper than coils. This is especially true of power circuits, which is how you tagged your question.